# Getting a syntax error when executing SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, embedded-database

I have the following method that drops the database but I get a syntax error and I dont know what is going on.

```
public void deleteDB(){
    try{
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Deleteting database...");
        s.execute("DROP DATABASE Courses");
        System.out.println("Database deleted.");
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        System.err.println("Unable to delete database.");
        error.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I call the method with:

```
UpdateDB update = new UpdateDB();
update.connectDatabase(dbName);
update.deleteDB();
```

I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "DATABASE" at line 1, column 6.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what kind of database are your using?

Comment: Java DB in NetBeans. I am using Derby.

Comment: Does the account you have used have permission to drop the database?

Comment: there does not seem to be a `drop database` http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/reference/sqlj28.html . Maybe you need `drop schema`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have a *database* called courses?  or a *table* named courses?

according to this: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop13.html

> There is no drop database command. To drop a database, delete the database directory with operating system commands.

Comment: I have a database named Courses. I was able to delete my table using a DROP Table command that worked fine.